# Creating a bash array, separated by new lines

Tags: bash, share

I am reading in from a .txt file which looks something like this:

```
:DRIVES
name,server,share_1
other_name,other_server,share_2
new_name,new_server,share 3
:NAME
```

which is information to mount drives.  I want to load them into a bash array to cycle through and mount them, however my current code breaks at the third line because the array is being created by any white space.  Instead of reading

```
new_name,new_server,share 3
```

as one line, it reads it as 2 lines

```
new_name,new_server,share 
3
```

I have tried changing the value of IFS to

```
IFS=$'\n' #and
IFS='
'
```

however neither work.  How can I create an array from the above file separated by newlines.  My code is below.

```
file_formatted=$(cat ~/location/to/file/test.txt)
IFS='
' # also tried $'\n'
drives=($(sed 's/^.*:DRIVES //; s/:.*$//' <<< $file_formatted))

for line in "${drives[@]}"
do
  #seperates lines into indiviudal parts
  drive="$(echo $line | cut -d, -f2)"
  server="$(echo $line | cut -d, -f3)"
  share="$(echo $line | cut -d, -f4 | tr '\' '/' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"

#mount //$server/$share using osascript
#script breaks because it tries to mount /server/share instead of /server/share 3
```

EDIT:

tried this and got the same output as before:

```
drives=$(sed 's/^.*:DRIVES //; s/:.*$//' <<< $file_formatted)
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done <<< "$drives"
```

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) first.

Comment: Following the directions for using a variable: while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done <<< "$drives" : did not work @chepner

Comment: What does `test_drives` contain?

Comment: Sorry, it is the same as drives, but I removed a layer of () to not make it an array, i.e. drives=$(sed 's/^.*:DRIVES //; s/:.*$//' <<< $web_formatted)

Comment: @chepner I added an edit

Comment: Eh? Bash arrays are, well, *arrays*. Their elements aren't "separated" by anything at all; they're stored as distinct C strings in memory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when creating an array from a string, I am looking to separate the large string into sub strings by new lines

Comment: ...so you mean you want to split on newlines *in the input*? The existing answer (and BashFAQ #1) are entirely appropriate, then.

Comment: ...if you "tried this" and it doesn't work (for any pertinent value of "this"), edit your question to provide enough details that someone else can reproduce your test and see it not work for themselves (a [mcve]). An assertion that something "doesn't work" isn't nearly as helpful as a description of *how* it doesn't work -- what it does instead, what errors are emitted, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to iterate over your file; no arrays needed.

```
{
  # Skip over lines until we read :DRIVES
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line = :DRIVES ]] && break
  done

  # Split each comma-separated line into the desired variables,
  # until we read :NAMES, wt which point we break out of this loop
  while IFS=, read -r drive server share; do
    [[ $drive == :NAMES ]] && break
    # Use $drive, $server, and $share
  done

  # No need to read the rest of the file, if any
} < ~/location/to/file/test.txt
```